# Use the -i option on ssh/scp

Tags: centos, ssh, rhel

I would like to setup the ability to log into my redhat server by specifying the -i option on ssh or scp command line. I have followed the steps according to google but it doesn't appear to work. Steps are:

```
On server:
su myuser
ssh-keygen -t rsa
accept all defaults

copy the id_rsa files to the client machine
attempt to ssh to the server with
ssh -i id_rsa myuser@server
```

Permissions are `-rw-------` for `id_rsa` and `-rw-r--r--` for `id_rsa.pub`. Is there anything I am missing? It's surprisingly difficult to find information on google about this option.

output with the -v option is this

```
OpenSSH_5.3p1, OpenSSL 1.0.0-fips 29 Mar 2010
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to server [192.168.6.97] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: permanently_set_uid: 0/0
debug1: identity file id_rsa type 1
debug1: identity file id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_5.3
debug1: match: OpenSSH_5.3 pat OpenSSH*
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_5.3
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(1024<1024<8192) sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
debug1: Host 'server' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /root/.ssh/known_hosts:34
debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password
debug1: Next authentication method: gssapi-keyex
debug1: No valid Key exchange context
debug1: Next authentication method: gssapi-with-mic
debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information
Credentials cache file '/tmp/krb5cc_0' not found

debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information
Credentials cache file '/tmp/krb5cc_0' not found

debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information


debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information
Credentials cache file '/tmp/krb5cc_0' not found

debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: id_rsa
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password
debug1: Next authentication method: password
myuser@server's password:
```

Comment: You have to copy the `.pub` file's contents to the `authorized_keys` of the server.

Comment: @muru My understanding is authorized_keys will authorise a certain user to connect from a certain host to my server without password. I believe this is the reverse of what I want. I wish to generate the key on the server, send the key to the client and allow anyone with that key to login. An admin in our company has done this and sent me a key which I can use to login to their server from any client. I have used it from windows and other linux boxes.

Comment: That's slightly off - `authorized_keys` will authorize *anyone* who has a private key corresponding to an entry in it from *any* host to connect to it without a password. The `username@host` and the end of the authorized_keys entries are purely comments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you created a key but you didn't configure the account on the server to authorize that key.

Copy the contents of `id_rsa.pub` to the server and add it to `~/.ssh/authorized_keys`.

Do not copy `id_rsa` to the server, and keep it protected. This file contains the private key and the server doesn't need to see that.

Note that if the key is stored in `~/.ssh` on the client and is called `id_rsa` in that directory, the `ssh` client will use it automatically, so you don't need to use the `-i` command line option to specify it.

Comment: My understanding is authorized_keys will authorise a certain user to connect from a certain host to my server without password. I believe this is the reverse of what I want. I wish to generate the key on the server, send the key to the client and allow anyone with that key to login. An admin in our company has done this and sent me a key which I can use to login to their server from any client. I have used it from windows and other linux boxes.

Comment: If an admin in your company has offered a private key to use, decline it and destroy it, because that key is not private to you like it is supposed to be. Private keys should never be shared. That admin is missing the point.

Comment: "I wish to generate the key on the server" — it would be preferable if you generated the key elsewhere than the server, to minimize the chance that it will be accidentally shared. You should generate it on the client from which you intend to use it, which is probably the PC you are physically sitting in front of. Load it into the SSH agent from there using `ssh-add` and now you can use it through all your sessions.

Comment: Yes, I agree, I was just thinking the same thing. After posting my comment above I worked out how to get it working (by appending the server's public key to its own authorized_keys file)

Comment: "My understanding is authorized_keys will authorise a certain user to connect from a certain host" — `authorized_keys` does not place any restrictions on which host you are coming from. It authorized whoever possesses the matching private key to log in.

Comment: I have to ask, is it any worse than an admin sending me a password? With a password I cannot be sure no one else has the same password.

Comment: I should add I am using your suggested approach, I have asked the user to generate a key for me, I'm just curious. Is the advantage that that user is protected in that they know no one else can login as them?

Comment: If you receive a password by email then you change it right away, right? So it's not perfect but it's not awful. But you cannot change an ssh key, you have to generate a new one. So that's the difference. As to your other question, yes, the principle of any private credential, be it a private key or a password, it that it's something that only YOU know. If you still have other questions, try security.stackexchange.com.